# How much does Coffee Exchange care about being welcoming to new users?

Tags: discussion, support

I am a relatively experienced Stack Exchange user and have been on other Exchanges for a few years. This is the frostiest welcome I'm ever received.

One thing that's new for me on this Exchange, though, is to have found myself harassed by a commenter who decided to doubt the facts of my post really without much of a purpose. This commenter decided to be overly skeptical over my report of a coffee maker that a mostly plastic boiling pot (it's easy to verify that appliances like this exist). It's strange behavior I've never experienced on other Exchanges. Skepticism abounds, but usually not that kind of naked trolling.

Secondly, I then found myself getting lectured by a moderator about the "subjectivity" of my question. It's insulting, frankly. There's little subjective about a quest for an electric Turkish Coffee maker without a plastic boiling pot. I actually think it's an important question for those who care about coffee, especially Turkish coffee.

I'd ask all participants in this exchange to consider whether they actually want this exchange to have new users. Exchanges, frankly, are two-way streets: Is a question on topic? Is it interesting and new? Other things being equal, that should be enough for a question to take flight. If that isn't sufficient for a good question, you shouldn't be surprised that there's a dearth of questions and users on here.

I invite all of the moderators here to reassess how welcoming this Exchange is to new users. I'm a passionate Coffee drinker and I've never had an issue as a participant on other Exchanges--I'm flexible, I generally listen to feedback, and I try to be helpful and clear. There's no reason why I couldn't fit in with this community.

Answer (score 3):

> One thing that's new for me on this Exchange, though, is to have found myself harassed by a commenter who decided to doubt the facts of my post really without much of a purpose. This commenter decided to be overly skeptical over my report of a coffee maker that a mostly plastic boiling pot (it's easy to verify that appliances like this exist). It's strange behavior I've never experienced on other Exchanges. Skepticism abounds, but usually not that kind of naked trolling.

I've reviewed the deleted comments on your post but I've come to a different conclusion. I think that other user was just confused about using plastic in an appliance that heats water. They left one comment which primary purpose to me seems to be to request information which was not included in your question at the time. For reference, this was the comment:

> Which part exactly was made from plastic and which product did you buy? I find it hard to believe that you can buy a device which basically heats water inside a plastic container where the plastic is in contact with the water. Also, it would be great if you could attach some pictures to your question for clarification.

If anything, the above comment was met with a harsh response that assumed the comment intended to be patronizing when it seems (to me) to be a request for further information primarily.

In situations like this, I recommend assuming good faith unless there's clear evidence not to. In this case, I'd say that evidence was lacking and any bad vibe you got from this initial interaction could be written up to different styles of communication.

---

> Secondly, I then found myself getting lectured by a moderator about the "subjectivity" of my question. It's insulting, frankly. There's little subjective about a quest for an electric Turkish Coffee maker without a plastic boiling pot. I actually think it's an important question for those who care about coffee, especially Turkish coffee.

The issue here isn't solely about subjectivity. That's just one of the reasons why product recommendation are off-topic, other reasons are given in [this meta question: *'Are product recommendations on-topic?'*](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5).

That's not to say that the spirit of your question is off-topic, it just has to be asked in a way that focuses on the technical aspect rather than the commercial one.

I can see how this can come across as a little insulting. I think that's a quirk of the Q&A format and community rules that force users to write questions from a certain perspective. Those community rules are in place intentionally.

For example, shopping questions are off-topic because they can be very localized and specific without being relevant to a lot of people. Instead, there are many aspects to shopping questions that can be phrased in general terms so that they become more relevant to everyone in a specific category of product.

I don't know to what extent this applies to Turkish coffee makers, but I can give an example for espresso machines. Let's say you're interested in temperature stability in espresso machines, then two aspects to look for are:

- single boiler vs dual boiler (or maybe even one without a boiler)
- PID or no PID

Those aspects are pretty much universal and users could make an informed decision if they know what to look for regarding those terms.

On the other hand, if they asked which machine offers the best temperature stability then the answers could skip the technical part and recommend specific machines. That might be good for most users in the next few years, but after some time those machines could be phased out or they may only be available in specific markets. As such, we've found that it's the technical knowledge that most useful to have on our site.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the initial commenter produced a second skeptical comment after I found a description of the product on Wayfair that was explicit about the plastic content. I also found a direct answer from the seller on Amazon, clarifying that the pot was *in fact* plastic on the inside. I had already returned the item so I wasn't going to produce pictures--to be frank, I had no responsibility to do so as the commenter's bad faith became clearer as time went on (btw, my original post was explicit about where the plastic is). We're very likely not going to agree on this.

Comment: @curiositasisasinbutstillcuriou the reason I only discussed the first comment is because you already assumed that comment to be in bad faith. As you pointed out in a now deleted comment to another user (no second request for clarification was posted by then): *"You may see it differently, but the commenter above was asking for the model and pictures more as a trolling exercise. I get that it's not really personal, but, at this age, I don't see it as my role to always accommodate the excessive skepticism of others."* To me, you seemed to assume bad faith when it wasn't there (yet).

Comment: I don't want this to become an intellectual exercise. Really, it turns out I wasn't mistaken about it being some kind of trolling. So I'm not going to apologize for that--bullies appear on other Exchanges and I don't think I need to take anything lying down.